# Failed to add participant into ongoing video call with Twilio sdk

Tags: android, video, twilio

Hi I am developing android application. I am using twilio for video calling feature.I am able establish one to one video call between two participant. I am also able to do video call with multiple participant. Only thing I am not able to add particiant into ongoing video call. As per api document following method should add particiant into call :

```
    //Send invite
outgoingInvite = conversationsClient.sendConversationInvite(participants, localMedia, new ConversationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConversation(Conversation conversation, ConversationException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Participant has accepted invite, we are in active conversation
            ConversationActivity.this.conversation = conversation;
        } else {
            hangup();
        }
    }
});

compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
```

I try to add this method into my code but it says `can not resolve symbol sendConversationInvite`. Is this method is depricated or not include into sdk. Or am I doing anything wrong. Need some help.

Comment: Which version of SDK you're using ?

Comment: Updated with versions. Please check question.